# Como generar numeros aleatorios que se puedan repetir determinada cantidad de veces

Tags: python

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
import random
Secuencia = []
for i in range(10):
    Aleatorio = random.randint(1,6)
    Secuencia.append(Aleatorio)
print(Secuencia)
```

Y de salida:

```
[1,4,6,6,6,6,2,4,5,3]
```

Como se puede apreciar existen 4 numeros 6 de corrido. La idea esque ya sea el numero 1,2,3, etc este no se repita una cierta cantidad de veces de manera continua. Es decir, que estos numeros generados no se pueden repetir mas de 3 veces seguidas. Ej:

```
[1,4,6,6,6,2,6,6,5,2]
```

La diferencia con el anterior radica en que el 6 no se repite mas de 3 veces y puede aparecer de nuevo despues de que exista otro numero. La idea es aplicarlo para todos los numeros... el 1, el 2 , el 3,etc. no se repitan 3 veces seguidas.

Comment: Quieres que se repitan menos de 3 veces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para resolver el problema que planteas usando el mismo For hice lo siguiente:

Como no quieres que un numero se repita 3 veces o mas primero hago que se generen 2 números aleatorios:

```
for i in range(10):
    if i < 2:
        Aleatorio = random.randint(1,6)
        Secuencia.append(Aleatorio)
```

ya que necesito saber si el numero que se va a generar es igual a los 2 generados e insertados en la lista haciendo uso de la posición en la lista:

```
  else:
        Aleatorio = random.randint(1,6)
        while Aleatorio == Secuencia[i-1] and Aleatorio == Secuencia[i-2]:
            Aleatorio = random.randint(1,6)

        Secuencia.append(Aleatorio)
```

ya que el for en este caso está operando con números positivos, después de i = 2 todos los números que siguen van a ser positivos uso el else. dentro del else declaro que Aleatorio va a almacenar un número aleatorio entre el 1 y el 6.
En el while pongo la condicion que si Aleatorio es igual al numero anterior que hay en la lista y al que le sigue al anterior (solo lo toma en cuenta si los 2 números son los mismos ya que si es asi tendriamos 2 numeros iguales en la lista y se estaria evaluando si el que se acaba de formar es el mismo que los ultimos 2 numeros de la lista. Mientras esta condición sea cierta se va a generar un nuevo número aleatorio hasta que no)

por lo que el código completo queda de la siguiente manera:

```
import random
Secuencia = []
for i in range(10):
    if i < 2:
        Aleatorio = random.randint(1,6)
        Secuencia.append(Aleatorio)
    else:
        Aleatorio = random.randint(1,6)
        while Aleatorio == Secuencia[i-1] and Aleatorio == Secuencia[i-2]:
            Aleatorio = random.randint(1,6)

        Secuencia.append(Aleatorio)

print(Secuencia)
```

y aquí unas pruebas para verificar que no se repite mas de 3 veces el mismo numero en la lista:

1. [5, 3, 1, 6, 6, 4, 6, 4, 3, 6]
2. [1, 1, 3, 3, 5, 3, 4, 6, 4, 4]
3. [4, 6, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2]

Espero siga a tiempo de ayudarte.

Answer (score 1):

Manteniendo tu lógica inicial, podrías hacer algo así:

```
import random

Secuencia = []
max_consecutivos = 3
while len(Secuencia) < 10:
    Aleatorio = random.randint(1,6)
    if len(Secuencia) >= max_consecutivos:
      if [Aleatorio] * max_consecutivos != Secuencia[-max_consecutivos:]:
        Secuencia.append(Aleatorio)
    else:
      Secuencia.append(Aleatorio)
```

Comentarios:

- Por ahí es una obviedad, pero esto ya deja de ser una generación aleatoria
- La idea es iterar hasta lograr la longitud deseada de la lista
- Con cada iteración verificar si la sub lista de los últimos 3 elementos es distinta al a una lista con 3 repeticiones del `Aleatorio`, en cuyo caso ya hemos llegado al máximo permitido y no lo podemos sumar a `Secuencia`